# Generating a table with two rows. one having a mean of data sorted by year. the second having a difference of data by year. using R

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and need help Generating a table with two rows. one having a mean of data sorted by year. the second having a difference of data by year. the Data isn't as important as how to link it to the years and then organizing it by year. any help or tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please share your data using `dput()`? Kindly provide the reproducible example.

Comment: Please include a simple, minimal reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions

Comment: Hi @Peyton, welcome on Stackoverflow. Check out [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/9406040) on how to ask a good `R` question that will lead to a quick and productive answer.